# In C# how I will get combobox values in other class which is not a form class

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, serial-port

This is my form class which has combo box

```
 public partial class Connect : Form
{
    Communication Comm = new Communication();


    public Connect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        COM_List();

    }
   public void COM_List()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Comm.GetCommList().Count; i++)
        {
            cb_CommPort.Items.Add(Comm.GetCommList()[i]);
        }
    }

    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((cb_CommPort.Text == "") || (cb_BaudRate.Text == "") || (cb_Parity.Text == "") || (cb_DataBits.Text == "") || (cb_StopBits.Text == ""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select all communication settings and then Save", "TestCertificate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            Comm.connect();

        }

    }
```

}

I need combo box values in my other class. The other class is below.
cb_CommPort, cb_BaudRate, cb_Parity, cb_DataBits, cb_StopBits. These all are combobox which does not work in this class

```
 public class Communication 
{
    public Communication()
    {

    }
    public List<string> GetCommList()
    {
        return (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToList());

    }
    private SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();
    public bool connect()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ComPort.IsOpen)
            {
                ComPort.Close();
            }
            ComPort.PortName = cb_CommPort.Text;
            ComPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(cb_BaudRate.Text);  //convert Text to Integer
            ComPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cb_Parity.Text);    //convert Text to Parity
            ComPort.DataBits = int.Parse(cb_DataBits.Text);                                    //convert Text to Integer
            ComPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cb_StopBits.Text);  //convert Text to stop bits

            ComPort.Open();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not open the COM port. Most likely it is already in use, has been removed, or is unavailable.", "TestCertificate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I tried all the tricks which is on net. But not yet resolved. Any help will be appropriated.

Comment: We need more context.  Where are you instantiating each of these classes?  Please provide us a [mcve].

Comment: That is my problem, that I can't instantiate instance of connect class in communication class. If I did so, I can not call  Comm.connect(); this method to connect class.

Comment: "If I did so, I can not call Comm.connect(); this method to connect class."  <-- why not?

Comment: If you want the items selected in combo box in the `Communication` , you should create properties for them in `Communication` class and assign them from `Connect` form.

Comment: I tried all. But nothing works. I am very new to programming.